# Completing the installation of the OpenSSL 3.0.2 FIPS Module

Tags: c, openssl

It's very early days yet but I've started migrating from OpenSSL 1.0.2 to 3.0.2. (Windows)

After building OpenSSL 3.0.2, to [complete the installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Completing_the_installation_of_the_FIPS_Module) you need to run the 'fipsinstall' command line application.

I did that using this command as suggested:

```
C:\WORK\c89f702a343c78ef949c71865ebdfc637541b638\bin\openssl.exe fipsinstall -out C:\WORK\c89f702a343c78ef949c71865ebdfc637541b638\fipsmodule.cnf
-module C:\WORK\c89f702a343c78ef949c71865ebdfc637541b638\lib\ossl-modules\fips.dll
```

> HMAC : (Module_Integrity) : Pass SHA1 : (KAT_Digest) : Pass SHA2 :
> (KAT_Digest) : Pass SHA3 : (KAT_Digest) : Pass TDES : (KAT_Cipher) :
> Pass AES_GCM : (KAT_Cipher) : Pass AES_ECB_Decrypt : (KAT_Cipher) :
> Pass RSA : (KAT_Signature) : RNG : (Continuous_RNG_Test) : Pass Pass
> ECDSA : (PCT_Signature) : Pass ECDSA : (PCT_Signature) : Pass DSA :
> (PCT_Signature) : Pass TLS13_KDF_EXTRACT : (KAT_KDF) : Pass
> TLS13_KDF_EXPAND : (KAT_KDF) : Pass TLS12_PRF : (KAT_KDF) : Pass
> PBKDF2 : (KAT_KDF) : Pass SSHKDF : (KAT_KDF) : Pass KBKDF : (KAT_KDF)
> : Pass HKDF : (KAT_KDF) : Pass SSKDF : (KAT_KDF) : Pass X963KDF :
> (KAT_KDF) : Pass X942KDF : (KAT_KDF) : Pass HASH : (DRBG) : Pass CTR :
> (DRBG) : Pass HMAC : (DRBG) : Pass DH : (KAT_KA) : Pass ECDH :
> (KAT_KA) : Pass RSA_Encrypt : (KAT_AsymmetricCipher) : Pass
> RSA_Decrypt : (KAT_AsymmetricCipher) : Pass RSA_Decrypt :
> (KAT_AsymmetricCipher) : Pass INSTALL PASSED

which created this config file **fipsmodule.cnf**

```
[fips_sect]
activate = 1
install-version = 1
conditional-errors = 1
security-checks = 1
module-mac = 3A:EC:2E:53:3F:92:44:F9:50:13:70:6E:FD:38:37:08:8B:F2:68:56:CC:B4:ED:5F:A1:52:1B:93:15:37:0B:8C
install-mac = 41:9C:38:C2:8F:59:09:43:2C:AA:2F:58:36:2D:D9:04:F9:6C:56:8B:09:E0:18:3A:2E:D6:CC:69:05:04:E1:11
install-status = INSTALL_SELF_TEST_KATS_RUN
```

However, a cautionary note about OpenSSL 3.0 states:

> ***You must not copy the FIPS module config file output data from one
> machine to another.***

Here's the layout of the folder containing the files needed to correctly generate the config file.

```
C:\WORK\c89f702a343c78ef949c71865ebdfc637541b638>tree /f /a
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 448B-63A8
C:.
|   conaninfo.txt
|   conanmanifest.txt
|   fipsmodule.cnf
|
+---bin
|       c_rehash.pl
|       openssl.exe
|
+---include
|   \---openssl
|           aes.h
|           asn1.h
|           asn1err.h
|           asn1t.h
|           asn1_mac.h
|           async.h
|           asyncerr.h
|           bio.h
|           bioerr.h
|           blowfish.h
|           bn.h
|           bnerr.h
|           buffer.h
|           buffererr.h
|           camellia.h
|           cast.h
|           cmac.h
|           cmp.h
|           cmperr.h
|           cmp_util.h
|           cms.h
|           cmserr.h
|           comp.h
|           comperr.h
|           conf.h
|           conferr.h
|           configuration.h
|           conftypes.h
|           conf_api.h
|           core.h
|           core_dispatch.h
|           core_names.h
|           core_object.h
|           crmf.h
|           crmferr.h
|           crypto.h
|           cryptoerr.h
|           cryptoerr_legacy.h
|           ct.h
|           cterr.h
|           decoder.h
|           decodererr.h
|           des.h
|           dh.h
|           dherr.h
|           dsa.h
|           dsaerr.h
|           dtls1.h
|           ebcdic.h
|           ec.h
|           ecdh.h
|           ecdsa.h
|           ecerr.h
|           encoder.h
|           encodererr.h
|           engine.h
|           engineerr.h
|           err.h
|           ess.h
|           esserr.h
|           evp.h
|           evperr.h
|           e_os2.h
|           fipskey.h
|           fips_names.h
|           hmac.h
|           http.h
|           httperr.h
|           idea.h
|           kdf.h
|           kdferr.h
|           lhash.h
|           macros.h
|           md2.h
|           md4.h
|           md5.h
|           mdc2.h
|           modes.h
|           objects.h
|           objectserr.h
|           obj_mac.h
|           ocsp.h
|           ocsperr.h
|           opensslconf.h
|           opensslv.h
|           ossl_typ.h
|           params.h
|           param_build.h
|           pem.h
|           pem2.h
|           pemerr.h
|           pkcs12.h
|           pkcs12err.h
|           pkcs7.h
|           pkcs7err.h
|           proverr.h
|           provider.h
|           prov_ssl.h
|           rand.h
|           randerr.h
|           rc2.h
|           rc4.h
|           rc5.h
|           ripemd.h
|           rsa.h
|           rsaerr.h
|           safestack.h
|           seed.h
|           self_test.h
|           sha.h
|           srp.h
|           srtp.h
|           ssl.h
|           ssl2.h
|           ssl3.h
|           sslerr.h
|           sslerr_legacy.h
|           stack.h
|           store.h
|           storeerr.h
|           symhacks.h
|           tls1.h
|           trace.h
|           ts.h
|           tserr.h
|           txt_db.h
|           types.h
|           ui.h
|           uierr.h
|           whrlpool.h
|           x509.h
|           x509err.h
|           x509v3.h
|           x509v3err.h
|           x509_vfy.h
|           __DECC_INCLUDE_EPILOGUE.H
|           __DECC_INCLUDE_PROLOGUE.H
|
+---lib
|   |   libcrypto.lib
|   |   libssl.lib
|   |
|   +---cmake
|   |       conan-official-openssl-variables.cmake
|   |
|   +---engines-3
|   \---ossl-modules
|           fips.dll
|           legacy.dll
|
\---licenses
    |   LICENSE.txt
    |
    \---external
        \---perl
            \---Text-Template-1.56
                    LICENSE
```

**Question**

As OpenSSL 3.0.2 is deployed to many machines, does it now require distributing the above files too and running the fips install to create a server specific config file? Seems quirky to have all this extra baggage rather than just copying the config file across machines. Why not use the same config (maybe MAC address dependent)? Why is this config needed at all?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSSL 3.0 FIPS module configuration file](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2022-February/014887.html)

> Please note that there are two checksums in the configuration file.
> One of them is the FIPS module checksum and the other is the checksum
> of the configuration. You can copy the file across machines if it is
> without the configuration checksum - that means the selftest will be
> always run when the FIPS module (i.e., the fips provider) is loaded.
>
> You cannot copy the file if the configuration checksum is present in
> it though because that means the selftest won't be run on the machines
> where you copy the configuration file to. That would be against the
> FIPS implementation guidance that requires to run the selftests at
> least once after the installation.

It looks like the openssl.cnf can be copied across machines if it has this defined without **install-mac** and **install-status**:

```
config_diagnostics = 1
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect

[provider_sect]
fips = fips_sect
base = base_sect

[base_sect]
activate = 1

[fips_sect]
activate = 1
install-version = 1
conditional-errors = 1
security-checks = 1
module-mac = 3A:EC:2E:53:3F:92:44:F9:50:13:70:6E:FD:38:37:08:8B:F2:68:56:CC:B4:ED:5F:A1:52:1B:93:15:37:0B:8C
```

The fipsmodule.cnf has this format:

```
[fips_sect]
activate = 1
install-version = 1
conditional-errors = 1
security-checks = 1
module-mac = 3A:EC:2E:53:3F:92:44:F9:50:13:70:6E:FD:38:37:08:8B:F2:68:56:CC:B4:ED:5F:A1:52:1B:93:15:37:0B:8C
install-mac = 41:9C:38:C2:8F:59:09:43:2C:AA:2F:58:36:2D:D9:04:F9:6C:56:8B:09:E0:18:3A:2E:D6:CC:69:05:04:E1:11
install-status = INSTALL_SELF_TEST_KATS_RUN
```